# Meaning of "There exists a proper class of..."

Tags: set-theory, definition

How a statement of the form [*"There exists a proper class of..."*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22There+exists+a+proper+class+of%22) can be formalized in $\sf ZFC$? It sounds a bit like an oxymoron to me, because it's the very essense of a proper class that it does not exist, only its elements (as identified by some predicate) exist.

I've never seen a definition that would assign a formal meaning to statements of this form, but my understanding that I inferred from context is as follows:

Let $P(x)$ be a predicate with a free variable $x$. The statement *"There exists a proper class of objects satisfying $P$"* means $\nexists y\,\forall x((x\in y)\iff P(x))$ (i.e. *"There is no set containing exactly those objects satisfying $P$"*).

---

Does this understanding match a commonly accepted one?

Comment: Perhaps it's NBG and not ZFC. There are proper classes in NBG.

Comment: Your formalization is fine. One way of thinking about this is that for any set $X$, there is a $y$ satisfying $P$ and not in $X$. Another way (which is probably how most set theorists think about these things) is that there are unboundedly many ordinals $\alpha$ such that there is an $x$ satisfying $P$ and of rank $\alpha$, that is, the witnesses to $P$ are unbounded in the universe.

Comment: Interestingly, your link leads to a Google search which has this very question as its first hit. That seems to hint that perhaps this phrasing is not very common. (In the great majority of the other hits, the proper class always seems to be a proper class of "Woodin cardinals", whatever that is ...)

Comment: @Henning: Google is known to filter and order results based on the user searching them. Meaning that what you and I search might not have the same result. So I wouldn't be hasty to infer these conclusions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematics is communicated in natural language, ultimately.

This means that we write phrases which might not be formally correct, but are well understood by everyone who is familiar with the context.

"There exists a proper class of $\varphi$" means that the collection $\{x\mid \varphi(x)\}$ is a proper class. Certainly this collection is definable, and when we say "there exists a proper class" we mean to say that there does not exists $A$ such that the collection defined by $\varphi$ is a subset of $A$.

So when we say that there exists a proper class of singletons we mean that there is no set of all singletons; and there exists a proper class of vector spaces over $\Bbb R$ we mean there is no set of all vector spaces over $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we talk about the proper class of something well ordered such as cardinals. In which case you can substitute unbounded, 
$$\forall \kappa \exists \lambda  > \kappa P(\lambda)$$ means that there is a proper class of cardinals satisfying $P$.
In general you can use the cumulative hierarchy, 
$$\forall \kappa \exists x( \text{Rank}(x) > \kappa \wedge P(x))$$ says that there is a proper class of sets $x$ satisfying $P$.